# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip: flickers when placed on top of button, but works fine when placed at the left/right/bottom

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am dealing with some weird behavior for an instance of bootstrap's tooltip.

The page I am working with has several buttons that, when hovered over, display tooltips with the description for the buttons' functionality. The tooltips are all displayed on top of the buttons, and, with the exception of one button, everything works fine. This one button displays the tooltip with a continuous flickering, the tooltip itself covers part of the button (instead of being completely on top of the button), and prevents the button from being properly clicked. If the "data-placement" for the tooltip is changed from "top" to "left"/"right"/"bottom", the tooltip is displayed correctly.

Additionally, the button that gives me problems is wrapped in a div that has "float: right;" assigned in the css. I am mentioning this because I noticed that if I remove the float, the tooltip works fine. Unfortunately, if I remove the float, the button itself loses its correct positioning.

While I could give up the "top" positioning for the tooltip, I was hoping that there might be an easy trick to this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Update:

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979837/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-not-aligning-correctly-when-it-is-going-to-go-outside) presents the same problem as the one I was encountering. I found the answer useful.

Comment: Can you wrap the button in an element that's floated right and don't float the button?  See if that fixes it?  Instead of floating right, can you put it in an element (paragraph, div, whatever) and text-align right to give it the desired placement?

Comment: The button is actually wrapped in an element that is floated right - sorry for not being clear about this. The css itself is quite messy; I am dealing with elements from 3 different backbone views and ordering them correctly proved to be quite tedious. After trying several ways I decided to go with the current css, which does the trick, but most likely is not optimal. Due to time constraints, it would be preferable if the solution did not require significant css changes.

Comment: If you have it solved, I suggest either 1) posting the solution and marking it as such yourself; or 2) deleting this question.  Good luck with the project.

Comment: I have the same problem, but only with Chrome browser, when the tooltip is inside an iframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a quick solution for my problem. Although relatively short, my initial tooltip description was getting split on two lines. By chance, I tried shortening the tooltip text to fit on a single line. Once this was done, the tooltip was properly displayed. Therefore, I am assuming there must be a problem with the length of the tooltip text and the fact that the button is displayed all the way to the right of the page (and at the top of the page). I will not investigate this further for the time being.

Answer (score 101):

Add to the tooltip `pointer-events: none;` css rule, like

```
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent tooltip from being target for mouse events and will resolve the issue.

Comment: Clean, straightforward, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: What if the tooltip is added to an hyperlink? This will cancel the click action from it?

Comment: this totally solved the issue for me - thanks!

Answer (score 29):

## Read The Docs

The [docs on Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/#usage) explicitly address this issue and also provide a solution:

> Overflow auto and scroll
>
> Tooltip position attempts to automatically change when a parent container has overflow: auto or overflow: scroll like our .table-responsive, but still keeps the original placement’s positioning. To resolve, set the boundary option to anything other than default value, 'scrollParent', such as 'window':
>
> `$('#example').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' })`

So we have to set the `boundary` option to `'window'`.

From the [docs on the `boundary` option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/#options):

> Overflow constraint boundary of the tooltip. Accepts the values of 'viewport', 'window', 'scrollParent', or an HTMLElement reference (JavaScript only). For more information refer to Popper.js's [preventOverflow docs](https://popper.js.org/docs/v1/#modifiers..preventOverflow.boundariesElement).

## Best Practice

That being said, the [preferred way of initializing tooltips everywhere](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere) is to use `'[data-toggle="tooltip"]'` as selector:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' })
```

## Once And For All

Now if you are dynamically adding or removing elements (with tooltips) to the DOM or are even replacing the whole page without reloading it (i.e. by using a `pushState` library like [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)) - or if you are just using modals (with tooltips) - you have to initialize those tooltips (again).

#### Fixing Tooltips On Elements

That's where the following function comes in handy, which destroys and recreates all tooltips. Call this function after you've added / removed an element to / from the DOM that has / had a tooltip attached.

```
function recreateTooltips() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose').tooltip({boundary: 'window'});
}
```

This might seem expensive (and certainly is), but I've never noticed any performance impact even with dozens of tooltips on the same page.

#### Fixing Tooltips In Modals

To fix tooltips in modals, you simply bind the function from above to the `'shown.bs.modal'` event, which fires after a modal is fully shown to the user.

```
/** Recreate tooltips upon showing modal */
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '*', function () {
    recreateTooltips();
});
```

Comment: Works for me adding the boundary

Comment: This solution sounded great, but it doesn't work (Bootstrap 4.5)

Answer (score 6):

I was having this same issue.  I found that Bootstrap's tooltips do not position themselves correctly over "floated" or "inline/inline-block" elements when those elements are within a container with relative or absolute positioning.  I have a button floated right, inside an absolutely positioned parent container.  If I remove the absolute positioning of the parent, the tooltip displays perfectly fine.  Bootstrap needs to address this.

Answer (score 3):

This happens on inline elements, such as `a` tags. Setting the `display` property to `block` resolves the issue.

Comment: Similarly, I was able to workaround the issue by adding the property (container="body") to my button.

Answer (score 3):

Late response, but I had this same issue and was able to resolve it by using the 'container' option in the tooltip jquery reference on the html element.

See this [page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11113) and the jsfiddle link therein.

You can see the tooltip container option details [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Answer (score 2):

Building on Steve's answer, I found the issue was that my css reference to the font awesome css was ***after*** the bootstrap css.  The bootstrap css sets the display property for font awesome icons to be "inline-block".

So to fix the issue I just moved the bootstrap css reference after the font awesome css and this fixed the flickering issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much control you have over Bootstrap bits, but it sounds like the hover event is constantly firing. The way to stop this would be to use .stop() before the call, but I'm not sure if that's possible here, for example:

```
$('#myelement').stop().fadeOut(200);
```

I don't know if you're able to do something like that with the Bootstrap call, but it may be worth giving it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I had this flickering problem because my buttons were hidden at first.  Triggering tooltips on hidden elements will not work.  I made my own tooltips that look just like the bootstrap tooltips.

```css
.tooltip1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip1 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: visible;
  top: -300%;
  left: -300%;

  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip1:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">   <button routerLink='/members/{{member.username}}' class="btn btn-primary">
            <div class ="tooltip1"><span class="tooltiptext">Click this button to view the details of this person.</span>  <i class="fa fa-user"></i></div></button></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above fixed the issue for me (using standard bootstrap generated css).

The dialog popup partially overlapped the (i) icon. Just move it down a little like so and no more flicker:

```
.popover {
    margin-top: 18px !important;
}
```