# Show bootstrap tooltip after $().show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

From bootstrap:

> Don't try to show tooltips on hidden elements
>
> Invoking $(...).tooltip('show') when the target element is display: none; will cause the tooltip to be incorrectly positioned.

But what happens if I first $('el').show(); then $('el tooltips).tooltip()?

Why it still does not work?

Comment: What is the element `el`? Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: have you tried to add tooltip on an element that is already shown? Just to confirm if it's a css issue or a javascript issue.

Comment: Yes, if you call tooltips after `show()` they will work https://jsfiddle.net/a1gdubuq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an issue with your css, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979837/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-not-aligning-correctly-when-it-is-going-to-go-outside), however if you just want to make sure that your code is executed exactly after the element is shown, then use this code

```
$(yourElement).show(0, function () {
 $(this).find('.tooltips').tooltip();
});
```